# Text alignment in Dialog Box for Import Text

Tags: javascript, android

I create alert dialog and get name, address etc. from URL but in dialog box some text appears below the address text. i want to set text in alignment only on text of URL not Name and address.

This happen
Name     : Mihir patel
Address  : 25/mira nagar,
gopal chock....
gopal chock is starting from below the address I want them after some space.

```
            tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
            tv.setText("Name            : " + info.get_name());


            tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_address);
            tv.setText("Address     : " + info.get_address());
```

Comment: Please share some code

Comment: u can set all text in single textview. like tv.settext("Name:"+info.get_name()+" Address:"+info.get_address());

Comment: and if you dont want your textview to go in next line set its singleLine property.

Answer (score 0):

Your entire attempt here is doomed to fail, because you're trying to space it out with ' ' characters.  That will never work, because font sizes will differ when font sizes and text scaling settings are taken into account.  The correct way to do this is to use separate text views for the labels and the values, and to align them in the xml.